# Salvar arrays duplicados em um Insert

Tags: php, mysql

Tenhos arrays duplicados

```
produto[] valor[] qtd[] total[]
produto[] valor[] qtd[] total[]
```

Preciso salvar esses arrays em um insert, assim:

```
INSERT 'tabela' (produto, valor, qtd, total) VALUES (produto[],valor[],qtd[],total[]) ;

INSERT 'tabela' (produto, valor, qtd, total) VALUES (produto[],valor[],qtd[],total[]) ;
```

//OBS: sei que isso nos VALUES não funciona mas é isso que preciso...

JÁ FIZ ASSIM:

```
    foreach ( $produto as $key => $v) {
    $array[$key][] = $v;
}

    foreach ( $valor as $key => $v) {
    $array[$key][] = $v;
}

    foreach ( $qtd as $key => $v) {
    $array[$key][] = $v;
}

    foreach ( $total as $key => $v) {
    $array[$key][] = $v;
}

    foreach ( $modalidade as $key => $v) {
    $array[$key][] = $v;
}

    foreach( $array as $value){ 

echo "INSERT INTO `table` ( `produto`, `valor`,`qtd`,`total`,`modalidade`) VALUES (".$value[0].",".$value[1].",".$value[2].",".$value[3].",".$value[4].")

}
```

OBS:
Está funcionando, o fato é que nem sempre no value[0] é o produto, e o value[1] é o valor e assim por diante....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce pode fazer algo desse tipo:

```
$i=0;
$sql= "INSERT 'tabela' (produto, valor, qtd, total) VALUES ";
while(!empty(produto[$i]){
 $sql=$sql."($produto[$i],$valor[$i],$qtd[$i],$total[$i]),";
$i++;
 }
 $sqlFinal = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)-1);
```

Ou uma outra forma seria essa:

```
$i=0;
$sql= "INSERT 'tabela' (produto, valor, qtd, total) VALUES ";
foreach($produto as $p){
$sql=$sql."($p,$valor[$i],$qtd[$i],$total[$i]),";
$i++;
}
 $sqlFinal = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)-1);
```

Aí você vai ter o sql montado na variavel $sql

Comment: Olá amigo, estou trabalhando com mais dados não apenas os que estão no código de exemplo da pergunta, então verificando se o produto está preenchido não adiantaria pois estou recebendo mais dados pelo $_post

Comment: Acho que não compreendi o que quis dizer...

Comment: Editei ali, ve se é isso...

Comment: editei a pergunta, mostrando como estou fazendo.. pois não consegui do jeito que me falou...

Comment: Não entendi o que você fez ali... Voce tentou da maneira que coloquei ali? porque se a chave dos seus arrays forem numeros, a cada foreach vai sobrepor o valor do foreach anterios, pode dar um `var_dump($array);`para voce conferir o valor qe esta dentro do array

Comment: Fiz um teste com a sua segunda opção e o resultado ficou assim: >" INSERT 'tabela' (produto, valor, qtd, total) VALUES ,(camiseta,99.00,1,99.00),(calca,199.00,1,199.00) " Só que não funciona com a virgula depois do VALUES....

Comment: Editei ali, mudei a virgula,então no final vai sempre ter uma virgula. Depois é só remover com a linha que adicionei, a ultima virgula. Acho que é isso

Comment: Perfeito amigo! Muito obrigado...